# asp.net mvc2 login failed with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

i am using asp.net mvc2 with mysql db. i add mysql membership provider,profileprovider,role provider for mysql.the i use asp.netconfiguration tool to create roles.it works and create roles.then i try to login at that time it shows The user name or password provided is incorrect.when i create role defaul mysql membership,role tables are created in the database.

my wb config provider initialization part is as follows.

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />


    <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"  connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="MYAPP"  writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" autogenerateschema="True" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="False" requiresUniqueEmail="False"  maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" autogenerateschema="true" />
  </providers>
  </profile>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add  name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.3.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"  connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" autogenerateschema="true"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

any one know why it doent allow to login.

Answer (score 0):

I know its the obvious - but have you gone into the new db and ensured the login information and password are indeed correct?
You mentioned you created the roles - but no mention of creating the users, which you would need to do in the aspnet tool as well.

Comment: i create user also.then i try to login using that username and password it showing username or password provided is incorrect